# May I use DockLayoutPanel in DialogBox in GWT

Tags: gwt, dialog, docklayoutpanel

I' m tying to make a dialog box that contains 3 parts: `TextBox`, `DataGrid` and `Button`. And I'm using `DockLayoutPanel` like that

```
<ui:style>
    .panel {
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames='{style.panel}'>
    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
       <g:north size="45">
          <g:TextBox>...
       </g:north>
       <g:south size="45">
          <g:Button>...
       </g:south>
       <g:center>
          <g:DataGrid>...
       </g:center>
    </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Here is my class

```
public class MyDialogBoxViewImpl extends DialogBox {
 interface MyDialogBoxViewImplUiBinder extends
    UiBinder<Widget, MyDialogBoxViewImpl> {
    }
...
```

But the problem is that only `TextBox` is visible.
I'm not sure that it is properly to use `DockLayoutPanel` in `DialogBox`, but it is so suitable for my application. So can you help me with my issue and give me some advices how to replace `DockLayoutPanel` if it will need. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting explicitly the size of DockLayoutPanel ? Like: <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="100%" height="100%">

Comment: @philfr49, you are right. Can you post your comment as answer to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting explicitly the size of DockLayoutPanel. 
For example:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your size values are "100%", but your unit is "PX". Try changing your unit to "PCT" for percentage width and height